# Php inner join and display results

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 database:

- one which holds the user
- second which holds schedules Year, Month, Date, Day id of user.

on my `show.php`

I have a calendar which runs using php. I need to display the user which has the same date with the calendar like:

1. user1,user2
2. 
3. user1
4. user2

and so on.

```
private function _showDay($cellNumber){         
    if($this->currentDay==0){             
        $firstDayOfTheWeek = date('N',strtotime($this->currentYear.'-'.$this->currentMonth.'-01'));                     
        if(intval($cellNumber) == intval($firstDayOfTheWeek)){                
            $this->currentDay=1;                 
        }
    }
    if( ($this->currentDay!=0)&&($this->currentDay<=$this->daysInMonth) ){
        $this->currentDate = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($this->currentYear.'-'.$this->currentMonth.'-'.($this->currentDay)));
        $cellContent = $this->currentDay;
        $this->currentDay++;   
    }else{
        $this->currentDate =null;
        $cellContent=null;
    }    
    $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'a', 'emp') 
    or die ('Cannot connect to db');
            $sqlday="SELECT emp.name, emp.id, tbl_data.id,tbl_data.year, tbl_data.month, tbl_data.date
                    FROM emp
                    INNER JOIN tbl_data ON emp.id = tbl_data.id 
                    WHERE tbl_data.year = $currentYear
                    AND tbl_data.month = $currentMonth 
                    AND tbl_data.date = $currentDate";
            $resultday = mysqli_query($conn,$sqlday);

    return '<p id="li-'.$this->currentDate.'" class="daycounts">'.$cellContent. ''.$resultday.'</p>';
}
```

Comment: you never fetched record from executed query. so how you will print?

Comment: Store dates as dates, and see about parametrised queries